# sending ajax to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm new to rails and i got a problem of sending ajax to the controller:

there is a link_to of the html:

```
<%= link_to "回复", {:controller=>"activites", :action=>"add_in_comment"},...%>
```

and when i click it ,i send a ajax to the controller action of "add_in_comment" with a post request.

```
$(".each_comment .comment").on("click",function() {
    var post_data = {
        comment_to_id:$(this).attr("data-test1"),
        content:$(this).siblings("input").val(),
        comment_from_id:$(this).attr("data-cur_u"),
        activity_id:$(this).attr("data-activity_id")
    }
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: $("#comments a.expand").attr("href"),
        data: post_data,
        success: function(){

            },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

however i got the wrong routing info as follows:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/activites/1"):
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/activites/1"
```

and it seems that the action didn't execute.

the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


get 'account/login'

  get 'account/register' 

  get 'activites/all-events'

  post 'activites/add_in_comment'

  get 'launch' => 'activites#new'

  get 'nuts/index'

  get 'hole/all-holes'

  post 'account/login'

  post 'account/register'

  post 'activites/add'

  get 'account/logout'



  delete 'activites/delete'

  post 'activites/add_comment'


    root 'nuts#index'
    resources :nuts
    resources :activites
    resources :hole
    resources :account

end
```

the action in the controller is as follows:

```
def add_in_comment
    to = params[:comment_to_id]
    content = params[:content]
    from = params[:comment_from_id]
    activity = params[:activity_id]
    com = CommentActivity.create(:activity_id =>activity, :content => content, :from_id =>from, :to_id => to)
    if com

    else 
        puts "-----------------------wrong"
        puts com.errors.full_messages
    end

end
```

and i wanna know how the controller send response to the ajax.thx:)

Comment: I guess the url you pass to jquery ajax function is undefined. `console.log($("#comments a.expand"))` that.

Comment: @preciz. the url is /activites/add_in_comment

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :activities do
   post :add_in_comment #-> url.com/activities/:activity_id/add_in_comment
end

#view
<%= link_to "回复", activity_add_in_comment_path(@activity) %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(documet).on("click", ".each_comment .comment", function() {
    var post_data = {
        comment_to_id:$(this).attr("data-test1"),
        content:$(this).siblings("input").val(),
        comment_from_id:$(this).attr("data-cur_u")
    }
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: $("#comments a.expand").attr("href"),
        data: post_data,
        success: function(){

            },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

---

The problem you have is that you've *likely* defined your `post 'activites/add_in_comment'` below your `resources :activities`:

```
resources :activities
post "activities/add_in_comment"
```

The problem with this is that Rails *matches* any incoming route with a route defined in your routes file. When you define `resources :activities`, it automatically sets `url.com/activities/:id` as a route to the show action (which is what I believe your error to be).

Adding [extra routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to your `activities` resource should solve the issue.

---

Wow your routes can be fixed:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'nuts#index'
    resources :nuts, only: :index
    resources :holes, path: "hole", only: [] do
        get :all-holes, on: :collection
    end
    resources :activities, path_names: { new: "launch", create: "add" } do
        get  :all_events,     on: :collection
        post :add_in_comment, on: :collection
        post :add_comment,    on: :member
    end
    resources :accounts, path: "account", path_names: { create: "add" } do
        match :login,    on: :collection, via: [:get, :post]
        match :register, on: :collection, via: [:get, :post]
        get :logout,     on: :collection
    end
end
```

I'm not going to pick through your code for you. I would say you can use [`respond_with`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) or [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) to send data back to ajax requests:

```
#app/controllers/activities_controller.rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
   def add_in_comment
       # do stuff
       respond_to do |format| 
          format.js   { ... }
          format.html { ... }
       end
   end 
end
```

Comment: i didn't add any other "post 'activites/add_in_comment'" in the routes.rb and when i click the link_to ,i just in the url path of "...//activites/1".and what i want is i click it and send an ajax to the controller and then refresh partial where i send the ajax.

Comment: Can you show your routes? I might have been wrong :)

Comment: i post it @Rich Peck